# how to convert .png to .bmp using winapi?

Tags: c, winapi

Using **C** language

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is something like DevIL not an option? Cause there, it becomes something like `ilLoadImage()`, `ilSaveImage()` to do the conversion. Easier than the WinAPI and not horribly heavy.

Comment: It would have taken about 2 seconds to find that the Windows API does not include image manipulation functions.

Comment: Well, it does, `<gdiplus.h>` is a standard header.  Not for C programmers though.  libpng is their lot.  Why you'd use C to do a C++ job is something that I stopped understanding about 15 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Window Imaging Component API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719654%28VS.85%29.aspx). See [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500647.aspx).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component says that's only available in Vista and XP SP3.

Comment: msdn says it ships with vista and win7 and is downloadable for win xp

Answer (score 1):

I have only used it via .NET but the underlying standard Windows lib GDI+ might be what you're after.
[Here's the MSDN intro page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Its worth adding that GdiPlus has a C++ AND a C API.